# What is the density of compressed natural gas (CNG) used in vehicles?

Tags: gas-laws, hydrocarbons, density

I would like to know the density of the compressed natural gas used for natural gas vehicles in order to complete the formula in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141752/339790) Mathematics Stack Exchange post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density of CNG at the pressure of 200 bars (which is optimized for use in vehicles) is 435 $\frac{kg}{m^3}$. However, it's (not usually) 175 $\frac{kg}{m^3}$ in some vehicles in some countries. Note that it differs according to your home country.
 [Source 1](http://www.chive-ltd.co.uk/chivefuels/ngvfuels.htm) and [source 2](http://www.np.co.tt/our-brands/cng/).

Comment: If I plug that number (175) into the formula in the other post. I get 74,399.95 miles per gallon. That does not make sense with the data I have been given. This does not mean that your answer is wrong though.